# Weird Page loading issue in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I've been working locally on my iMAC through the native LAMP stack and I'm developing a Magento installation. So far so good, until yesterday, after trying to run an n98-magerun task to clear the cache (unsuccessfully I might add, don't know why thats not working either), it seems that something within the installation went kaput and now when I try to get to the home page of the magento installation, it WILL NOT load. It hangs for about two minutes before finally giving me a "no Data Received" Chrome screen.

My console shows only one thing, which is

```
i18n-values: Missing value for "primaryParagraph"
```

Even more confusing is the fact that I can navigate to other known pages within the installation, and I do get to a 404 page, even though those pages should exist.

A quite thorough five hour long search regimen has produced no useable information on the error above, and there doesn't seem to be anything about things that can go wrong with magerun, so I'm completely stumped.

Thoughts, constructive comments, places I may have overlooked, and any other useful info would be extremely appreciated.

Disclaimer: I am not a magento expert, I only started working with it before christmas.

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out that if you var_dump() in certain areas in magento, this can chuck out so much info that the page is unable to render to begin with.

Stupid me.

Comment: Since this question is no useful for anyone else than you maybe you should delete it.

Comment: Perhaps you can expand on this answer, but yes. Also, perhaps you could close this questions and ask a different one, such as, "Why does `var_dump()` sometimes hang the server?" of "Is there a Magento equivalent of `var_dump()`?" (Spoiler: see `Varien_Object::debug()`.